# Deep convolutional autoencoder problem - encoding dimension too large

Tags: python-3.x, keras, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, autoencoder

I recently built a convolutional autoencoder, upon which I built a sling of other networks. I just now realized that I made a fundamental mistake (should have seen it way earlier too). I thought my encoded layer (i.e. the output of the maxpooling layer labeled 'encoder', see below) had 'encoding_dim' dimensions. However, it has way more than I thought. I wanted 144, but I got 144 x 12 x 12 (which is actually more dimensions than the input: 48x48x3).

This is the code for the autoencoder:

## Architecture

```
input_shape = (image_dim, image_dim, 3)

# Build model
autoencoder = Sequential()
autoencoder.add(Conv2D(encoding_dim, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu', input_shape=input_shape,
                       kernel_initializer='random_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros'))
autoencoder.add(BatchNormalization())
autoencoder.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))

autoencoder.add(Conv2D(encoding_dim, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu',
                       kernel_initializer='random_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros'))
autoencoder.add(BatchNormalization())
autoencoder.add(MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same', name='encoder'))

autoencoder.add(Conv2D(encoding_dim, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu',
                       kernel_initializer='random_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros'))
autoencoder.add(BatchNormalization())
autoencoder.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))

autoencoder.add(Conv2D(encoding_dim, (3, 3), padding='same', activation='relu',
                       kernel_initializer='random_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros'))
autoencoder.add(BatchNormalization())
autoencoder.add(UpSampling2D((2, 2)))

autoencoder.add(Conv2D(3, (10, 10), padding='same', activation='sigmoid',
                       kernel_initializer='random_uniform', bias_initializer='zeros'))
autoencoder.add(BatchNormalization())
```

And this is the model summary (image_dim is 48 --> 48x48x3-sized images, encoding dim is 144):

## Model summary

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
conv2d_1 (Conv2D)            (None, 48, 48, 144)       4032      
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_1 (Batch (None, 48, 48, 144)       576       
_________________________________________________________________
max_pooling2d_1 (MaxPooling2 (None, 24, 24, 144)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_2 (Conv2D)            (None, 24, 24, 144)       186768    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_2 (Batch (None, 24, 24, 144)       576       
_________________________________________________________________
encoder (MaxPooling2D)       (None, 12, 12, 144)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_3 (Conv2D)            (None, 12, 12, 144)       186768    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_3 (Batch (None, 12, 12, 144)       576       
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_1 (UpSampling2 (None, 24, 24, 144)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_4 (Conv2D)            (None, 24, 24, 144)       186768    
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_4 (Batch (None, 24, 24, 144)       576       
_________________________________________________________________
up_sampling2d_2 (UpSampling2 (None, 48, 48, 144)       0         
_________________________________________________________________
conv2d_5 (Conv2D)            (None, 48, 48, 3)         43203     
_________________________________________________________________
batch_normalization_5 (Batch (None, 48, 48, 3)         12        
=================================================================
Total params: 609,855
Trainable params: 608,697
Non-trainable params: 1,158
```

This has put me in quite a pickle with regards to the other networks as well, so I need to adjust the architecture and retrain everything.

Would anyone explain to me where I went wrong, and more importantly, how I can adjust the filters/kernels to make sure my encoded layer indeed has 'encoding_dim' dimensions?